# How to get IQ tag using smack Java?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

actually, the problem is when my xmpp client send a friend invitation, and then the recipient have Approve the invitation, the openfire server push again to the initiator/ invitation sender a subscription packet to be authorized, that's why I want to prevent this by automatically filter it using IQ tag and then automatically authorize it.

but with PacketListener, I can't get IQ tag...

How can I do this?

```
@Override
public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
    Log.i(TAG, "SECOND subscription");
    Log.d(TAG, "SECOND: "+packet.toXML());
    if (packet instanceof Presence) {
        Presence p = (Presence) packet;
        Log.d(TAG, "TYPE-Presence: "+p.getType());
        if (p.getType() != Presence.Type.subscribe)
        return;
        String from = p.getFrom();
        Log.d(TAG, "PACKET from: "+from);
        Notification notification = new Notification(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_more, mService.getString(
                R.string.AcceptContactRequest, from), System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        Intent intent = new Intent(mService, Subscription.class);
        intent.setData(Contact.makeXmppUri(from));
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(mService, from, mService
                .getString(R.string.AcceptContactRequestFrom, from), PendingIntent.getActivity(mService, 0,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT));
        int id = p.hashCode();
        mService.sendNotification(id, notification);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The incoming IQs can be filtered out by using the "IQTypeFilter" filter. This is a sample code that illustrates the method.

```
    connection.connect();

    /* packet listener: listen for incoming messages of type IQ on the connection (whatever the buddy) */
    PacketFilter filter = new IQTypeFilter(IQ.Type.SET); // or IQ.Type.GET etc. according to what you like to filter. 

    connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() { 
        public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
            // HERE YOU PUT YOUR CODE TO HANDLE THE IQ MESSAGE
        }
    }, filter);
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer a little bit. actually i do not know how handle the IQ message

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve it by using IQTypeFilter, which is a filter for IQ packet types:

```
public final class IQTypeFilter extends FlexibleStanzaTypeFilter<IQ> {

    public static final StanzaFilter GET = new IQTypeFilter(Type.get);
    public static final StanzaFilter SET = new IQTypeFilter(Type.set);
    public static final StanzaFilter RESULT = new IQTypeFilter(Type.result);
    public static final StanzaFilter ERROR = new IQTypeFilter(Type.error);
    public static final StanzaFilter GET_OR_SET = new OrFilter(GET, SET);

    private final IQ.Type type;

    private IQTypeFilter(IQ.Type type) {
        super(IQ.class);
        this.type = Objects.requireNonNull(type, "Type must not be null");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean acceptSpecific(IQ iq) {
        return iq.getType() == type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + ": type=" + type;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As defined in Javadoc, IQTypeFilter is a filter for IQ packet types. Returns true only if the packet is an IQ packet and it matches the type provided in the constructor. There are some examples for [the use of IQTypeFilter](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jivesoftware.smack.filter.IQTypeFilter)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer using **Smack 4.3.4**. I explicitly put comments in order to make my code clear.

```
   /**
     *  packet listener: listen for incoming messages of whith IQ as elelement
     *  exmaple of IQ : <iq from="mbula@domain" to="dedi@domain" type="get" >.......</iq>
     */
    public static void listenToStanzas(AbstractXMPPConnection connection){

        // IQ filter type. it can Be GET, SET, RESULT, ERROR
        //in my case I filter SET IQs
        StanzaFilter filter =  IQTypeFilter.SET;

        connection.addSyncStanzaListener(new StanzaListener() {
            @Override
            public void processStanza(Stanza packet) {
                //Put yoour code Here
            }
        }, filter);
    }
```